# Does "get paid" mean "receive the income"?

Tags: meaning

Does *get paid* mean *receive the income*? Is there any other difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Too short a context to comment on. *get paid* could mean several things.

> You'll *get paid* for your deeds - You'll receive good/bad fortune for all what you do. Here, *getting paid* has nothing to do with payment! 
>   You'll *get paid* for this work - Certainly, here, you receive the income (money).

Another interesting meaning is [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=get%20paid) where it means *obtaining cash through other than commonly respectable means.*